# I need to click twice on ,the button to display the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

In this react component, I want to render the data to the screen when the 'Submit' button is clicked by the user, but the button has to be pressed twice for the data to display.

Below is my code snippet:

```
class Invoice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], isLoaded: false, transId: "" ,flag:true,errorFlag:false,show:false,displayContent:"",invoice:"",invoiceXmlBody:"",invoiceResult:"",invoiceTransId:"",invoiceResultFlag:false,invoicedisplayFlag:false};

  }
handleChangeInvoice(e) {
    console.log("inside handleChangeInvoice");
    let invoiceXml = e.target.value;
    if (invoiceXml !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ invoiceXmlBody: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  handleSubmitInvoiceXml =e=>{
   console.log("*******************inside handleSubmitInvoiceXml***************");
   let url = "http://localhost:8080/postInvoiceXml";
   fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.invoiceXmlBody),
     })
     .then(res => res.json()).then(data=>
       {
    this.setState({items:data});
    console.log(this.state.items[0].status);
     console.log("response========="+JSON.stringify(data));
      if(data===undefined){
          this.state.invoiceResultFlag=true;
    }
    else{
      this.state.invoicedisplayFlag=true;
          }
    }
 ) }

  render() {
    console.log("---------------------------"+this.state.invoicedisplayFlag);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <br/>
          <label className="lable" style={{marginRight:19}}>
              InvoiceXml:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="invoiceXml" placeholder="Enter invoice xml"
                onBlur={this.handleChangeInvoice.bind(this)}  style={{marginLeft:15}} />

            </label><br/><br/>
             <input type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmitInvoiceXml} name="Submit" value="Submit" className="submitButton" />          
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>

            <div  className={this.state.invoicedisplayFlag?"showDisplay":"hide"}>
              {this.state.items.map((item,i) => (
                <div>
                <h2>Invoice No is: {item.invoiceNo}</h2>
                 <h2>Transaction id is: {item.transId}</h2>
                  <h2>Status: { item.status ? 'Success' : 'Failed' }</h2>
                 </div>
                       ))}
               </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

how can I resolve this?

Comment: You **should not** modify state directly (such as `this.state.invoiceResultFlag=..`). Use `this.setState` instead.

Comment: With " onDoubleClick" the component is not getting rendered at all

Comment: @hindmost...it hepled me to resolve the issue...Can u  please briefly explain me the reason behind this?

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that you _want_ to show the data when you click on the button twice, or that the data is only showing when you click on the button twice but that's not what you want. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: My issue was lyk data is only showing when I click on the button twice,but after I  use this.setState instead of modifying state directly,it got resolved

Comment: _Can u please briefly explain me the reason behind this?_ This is a side effect of direct mutation of the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easy to find why, basically you are setting a value in your state directly, you should do it using `setState()` [like the documentation says](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

so your code is:

```
if(data===undefined){
    this.state.invoiceResultFlag=true;
}
else {
    this.state.invoicedisplayFlag=true;
}
```

but it should be:

```
if(data===undefined){
    this.setState({invoiceResultFlag: true})
}
else {
    this.setState({invoicedisplayFlag: true});
}
```

another thing that I noticed is that you want to set an state after you set an state, then you can use the callback from `setState()`

```
this.setState({items:data}, ()=>{
    if(data===undefined){
        this.setState({invoiceResultFlag: true})
    }
    else {
        this.setState({invoicedisplayFlag: true});
    }
});
```

and finally, I dont personally like those 2 setState, it would be easier to do it everything in one place:

```
this.setState({
    items:data,
    invoiceResultFlag: !data,
    invoicedisplayFlag: !!data,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem where I was using onBlur to update the state of an input value.

I found changing onClick to onMouseDown to work

```
<input className="input-form" onBlur={(e)=>{this.setState({field1:e.target.value})}/>

<button className="submit-button" onMouseDown={()=>{this.submitForm()}}>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick function for that button just save a flag in the component state [Or local to your class] indicating if the button was clicked and if so execute the render logic AND reset the flag again